# Proving $A\cdot B=B\cdot A$ for all $B$ $\iff A=\lambda\cdot I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I consider a matrix $ A\in \mathbb{K}^{n,n} $. Then we have the following equivalence:

1.) $ A\cdot B=B\cdot A\quad \forall B\in \mathbb{K}^{n,n} $

2.) $ \exists \lambda\in \mathbb{K} \: A=\lambda\cdot I_n $ and $ I_n\in \mathbb{K}^{n,n} $ is the identity matrix.

Remark: $ \mathbb{K} $ is a field.

Proof. ,,2.) =>1.)" is quite trivial, because we have $ A\cdot B=\lambda\cdot I_n\cdot B=B\cdot (\lambda\cdot I_n)=B\cdot A $.

But I have no idea how I can (easily) proof the direction ,,1.) => 2.)". The first thing I did is to write out the multiplication like this:

$ A\cdot B=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\\vdots & & \vdots\\a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1n}\\\vdots & & \vdots\\b_{n1}&\cdots&b_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\\= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\cdot b_{11}+...+a_{1n}\cdot b_{n1}&\cdots&a_{11}\cdot b_{1n}+...+a_{1n}\cdot b_{nn}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\a_{n1}\cdot b_{11}+...+a_{nn}\cdot b_{n1}&\cdots &a_{n1}\cdot b_{1n}+...+a_{nn}\cdot b_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\\= \begin{pmatrix}b_{11}\cdot a_{11}+...+b_{1n}\cdot a_{n1}&\cdots&b_{11}\cdot a_{1n}+...+b_{1n}\cdot a_{nn}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\b_{n1}\cdot a_{11}+...+b_{nn}\cdot a_{n1}&\cdots &b_{n1}\cdot a_{1n}+...+b_{nn}\cdot a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\\=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1n}\\\vdots & & \vdots\\b_{n1}&\cdots&b_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\\vdots & & \vdots\\a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}=B\cdot A $

I wanted to make a column comparison to get the coefficients of A. But this seems to be very very complicated. Which fact(s) I could also use to get A? It is intuitively clear to me that $ I_n $ must be a candidate for $ A=\lambda \cdot I_n $ but why only $ I_n $?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to choose appropriate matrices $B$ to deduce the form of $A$.

For example, let $B=E_{11}$, the matrix that has a $1$ in the $(1,1)$ entry and $0$s elsewhere., Then $BA$ is a matrix that has the same first row as $A$, and $0$s elsewhere, whereas $AB$ is a matrix that has the same first *column* as $A$, and $0$’s elsehwere. Since $AB=BA$, that tells you that in the first row of $A$, the only nonzero entry is the $(1,1)$ entry, and the same for the first column. Using $E_{kk}$ you should be able to prove that $A$ is diagonal. Once you know it is diagonal, use other matrices (think elementary matrices) to show that all diagonal entries must in fact be equal to each other.